# When I submit my form it doesn't save the information in the database, I use laravel 8

Tags: request, migration, save, crud, store

When I submit my form it doesn't save the information in the database, instead it just refreshes the page, if I delete the relation with my request in the controller the record is saved in the db but since I can't use $request, the data null arrive

Controller

```
* @param  \App\Http\Requests\StoreProcessRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreProcessRequest $request)
    {            
         $this->validate($request,[
           'name'=>'required',
           'email'=>'required',
           'radicado'=>'required',
           'NIT'=>'required',
           'fecha'=>'required',
           'user_id'=>'required',
       
           ]);

       $process = new process;
       $process->name = $request->name;  
       $process->email = $request->email; 
       $process->radicado = $request->radicado; 
       $process->NIT = $request->NIT; 
       $process->user_id = $request->userId;     
       $process->save();
       
       return "Guardado";
    }
```

storeProcessrequest

```
* @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'NIT' => 'required',
            'fecha' => 'required',
            'radicado' => 'required',
            'user_id' => 'required',         
        ];
    }
```

process.blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-md-8" align="center">
                               <h1> {{ __('process') }}</h1>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('process.store') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="row mb-6">
                            <label for="radicado" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">  </label>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="radicado" type="text" class="form-control" name="radicado" placeholder=" radicado" required>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row mb-6">
                            <label for="fecha" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input  id="fecha" class="form-control"  type="text" name="Ingresar-fecha" placeholder="Fecha" 
                                    onclick="ocultarError();" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" required>
                            
                            </div>  
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mb-6">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                            </div>  
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mb-6">
                            <label for="NIT" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="NIT" type="text" class="form-control" name="NIT" placeholder="NIT" required>
                            </div>  
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mb-6">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-MAIL" required>
                            </div>  
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            @livewire('user-selector-component')
                        </div>
                                            
                        <div class="row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                
                               
                                
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Crear') }}
                                </button>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

route

```
Route::post('process.store', [App\Http\Controllers\ProcessController::class, 'store'])->name('process.store');
```

migration

id();
                $table->string('radicado');
                $table->string('fecha');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('NIT');
                $table->string('email');
                $table->foreignId('user_id');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('processs');
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en el campo "fecha", el name no coincidia antes: name="Ingresar-fecha", ahora: name="fecha" y eso era todo.

Comment: The question has been asked in english. The answer you gave is in spanish. It would be good to answer in the same question, so people sharing the same or similar problem and not speaking spanish understand the solution as well.